# Videoview with fullscreen mode not working good..!

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

i have tried **https://github.com/brightec/ExampleMediaController** and also **https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1906** but the problem is that once i go full screen mode all the controllers are not working in this second link example.

Did not find any reliable solution i want to go automatically fullscreen when screen orientation change..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationListener.html. You can check `onOrientationChanged(int orientation)` method to detect whether orientation has changed to landscape. According to it you can hide other things or enable your fullscreen mode in that function

Comment: I have implemented this listener but the issue is all about videoview not working well when orientation change i just want a fullscreen button in it but did not find any solution regarding to that..!!